# sql server equivalent of oracle regexp_like

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008

I am looking to filter out all non-floating point values from a column in my SQL server 2008.

Does anyone know whats equivalent of this Oracle regexp in SQL server???

```
regexp_like(tablename.columnName,'[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+')
```

I have `no admin rights` and I don't have `dbo.regexReplace()`

So it would eliminate anything that is not a number, a dot(.) or + and - signs.

Comment: -7.97E-05 is a floating point value

Comment: 7.97E-05 and 2.2421E-05 is just another way of writing .0000797 and .000022421. Are you sure you want to eliminate those?

Comment: I know that but nothing else is there for it to complain about :)

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL does not support regexp directly.

You have to create a CLR User-Defined Function in order to use regexp.